# Is the $|00\rangle$ basis the same as the $|\phi^+\rangle$ basis?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, terminology-and-notation

I am working on a problem where I have 4 entangled qubits. I want to trace out 2nd and 3rd qubits by projecting them onto the $|00\rangle$ basis. Is the $|00\rangle$ basis the same as the $|\phi^+\rangle$ basis? Or is there any difference?

I understand how to project to the $|00\rangle$ basis but am not sure about the $|\phi^+\rangle$ basis. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: 4 entangled qubits may be in many configurations encoded in a single state; to be able to help we would need more information about what is the entangled state of the four qubits.

Answer (score 1):

The $|\Phi^+\rangle$ basis is the corresponding Bell basis of the uniform superposition of both qubits equal to each other.

In more detail, given qubits $A$ and $B$, we have  [in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_state):

$$|\Phi^+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|0\rangle_A \otimes |0\rangle_B + |1\rangle_A \otimes |1\rangle_B)\tag 1$$

$$|\Phi^-\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|0\rangle_A \otimes |0\rangle_B - |1\rangle_A \otimes |1\rangle_B)\tag 2$$

$$|\Psi^+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|0\rangle_A \otimes |1\rangle_B + |1\rangle_A \otimes |0\rangle_B)\tag 3$$

$$|\Psi^-\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|0\rangle_A \otimes |1\rangle_B - |1\rangle_A \otimes |0\rangle_B).\tag 4$$

In shorthand, I would say $|\Phi^+\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}|00\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}|11\rangle.$

This is not the same as $|00\rangle$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I have 4 entangled qubits and I have to trace out 2 nd and 3rd qubits by projecting to $\phi^{+}$ basis, how to do it?

Comment: I recommend posting a new question, by explaining what you’ve done already and what you are stuck with.